# What configuration is loaded at login after user config?

Tags: bash, login, bashrc

I’m trying to bootstrap Gentoo Prefix and I’m hitting a snag because Prefix insists that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is unset in a login shell.

So I put `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at the very end of both my `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`.

Good. Now it’s unset in a normal shell. However, in a login shell it’s still set: :-(

```
⟩⟩⟩ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
⟩⟩⟩ env -i $SHELL <<< 'env | grep LD'
⟩⟩⟩ env -i $SHELL -l <<< 'env | grep LD'
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib:/software/oracle-ic-11.2
```

How is this even possible (I thought site configuration would be loaded *before* user configuration), and, more importantly, how do I prevent it?

I should note that this is on a cluster system, with two consequences:

1. I don’t have super user rights.
2. Some of the system configuration is a bit … special. So *if* it’s technically possible then I wouldn’t be surprised if the sysadmin overrode user config. But from my understanding of the Bash loading process [this shouldn’t be possible](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) (short of patching `/bin/bash`).

Comment: You could try to put in `.profile`

Comment: @janos According to my understanding, `~/.profile` is only read by Bash if `~/.bash_profile` doesn’t exist. I tried it regardless; no difference.